# Why I am getting Permission Denied error on /etc/cron.weekly?

Tags: permissions, cron

I want to execute one script weekly. I am trying to add the script to /etc/cron.weekly but I I am getting the following error.

`-bash: /etc/cron.weekly/sa-certificate-updates: Permission denied`

I'm getting error with `sudo` too! I don't know what's wrong! Maybe because `others` and `group` does not have write permission at `/etc/cron.weekly`.

Considering I don't have root access, What can I do to add script under `/etc/cron.weekly`?

I am sudoer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not root, you can't do this, this is reserved for system services.

Just set up a normal weekly cron job or ask your admin to add this task.

Otherwise, if you have sudo access, doesn't `sudo cp` not work?

Comment: let me try `cp`